# Specifying User Access Control with Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, authentication, authorization, amazon-cognito

Working on an issue with Amazon Cognito. So far I've made it so that to access my API endpoints you need a authorization token in the header for example

```
curl --location --request 
PUT 'https://endpoint.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/dev/users/<user_Id>/<item_id>' \
--header 'authorizationToken: bearer token'
```

What I can't figure out is how to make this a little more fine grained, because with this method if you have have user with user_id: **X** and another user with lets say user_id: **Y**
user **X** can interact with the same resources as user **Y** and vice versa. so lets say a user X sends this request to my endpoint

```
curl --location --request 
PUT 'https://endpoint.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/dev/users/X/ITEM1' \
--header 'authorizationToken: bearer token'
```

User Y can send the same request

```
curl --location --request 
PUT 'https://endpoint.execute-api.<region>.amazonaws.com/dev/users/X/ITEM1' \
--header 'authorizationToken: bearer token'
```

and mess with user X's data. So how do I configure cognito to give back a bearer token that only allows User X to interact with his/her items and user Y to interact with his/her items and not user X's items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to control direct access to AWS services (S3 and so on), you would use a Cognito Identity Pool which would help you assign identities and control access via standard IAM.

If I understand correctly though, the resource you want to control access on is your own API. In that case you have to manage that yourself, your API will have to check permissions (prevent vertical and horizontal privilege escalation) by getting the identity from the token (and the userInfo endpoint of Cognito), and allow or deny access in every request based on your rules, not different from a traditional non-Cognito application or API.

What Cognito can add to this is you can store custom properties (claims) for your users, which you can get from Cognito and use for authorization decisions.